# Wordpress resize/crop featured image on index page only

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

Are there any plugins or code I can write that will output the featured image for a post to crop at 700X300. I only need the image to crop on the main index file. On the single post I want to use the full sized image.

Comment: You could use jCrop, which is a JS plugin included in WordPress core.

Answer (score 0):

You can open your functions.php file in your wordpress theme and use the [set_post_thumbnail_size() function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail_size) Something like this.

```
set_post_thumbnail_size( 700, 300, $crop );
```

the $crop is true or false, if false it will try to proportionally crop the image. If true it will crop without worrying about proportions.

Another approach if you're not comfortable with this is to figure out what the class or ID of the images are, and style them with CSS. Something like this.

```
.featured-image {
  max-width: 700px;
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

using max-height and max-width will scale the image proportionally, and also make it responsive. You may even want to use a mixture of them both.

Edit: If you open up your index.php file and look for the function [the_post_thumbnail()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) you can wrap a div, or span around it and style the image with CSS. This is if you run into trouble with the above methods.